# Where does android phonegap application data saved?

Tags: android, cordova, storage, android-sqlite

I am using phone gap application, I need to store some data, If I use phonegap local storage database, Where does it saved in phone? Is there any possibility to store data in the application it self, instead of storing it in sd card or phone memory?

Comment: local storage  save data in browser memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use local storage then the data will be stored in browser's memory. it will not be saved on your Phone memory or SD Card.

However, if you want to store some data then you can create SQLite Plugin for PhoneGap and store the Sqlite DB either in Phone Memory or in SD Card.

unfortunately, its not possible to store the data in the Application itself.

Hope this helps..